# Routing Error : No route matches "/images/new" using scaffold code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I'm inexperienced with Rails, so I may be overlooking something basic, but I'm following the [Paperclip wiki's documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Usage) for adding image attachments and after modifying the related files as indicated there, `/images/new` works as expected, until the form is submitted (form partial has been modified to include a file-upload field for the attachment in place of the generated database fields). The response is this:

> Routing Error
>
> No route matches "/images/new"

And the rails server outputs this:

> Started POST "/images/new" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Mar 15 16:19:45 -0500 2011
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/images/new"):
>
> Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.0ms)

I created an Image model to allow for handling of each image attachment independently of the Project model which they will be associated with (haven't done any of that yet).

Here is my images/_form.html.erb :

```
<%= form_for :image, :as => @image, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <% if @image.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@image.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this image from being saved:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @image.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :img %><br />
    <%= f.file_field :img %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :project_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :project_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :alt %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :alt %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here is my routes.rb

```
App2::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :images
  resources :projects
  get "pages/about"
  get "pages/contact"
  root :to => "projects#index"
end
```

And `app/models/image.rb`:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file   :img
#                       :styles => {    :thumb => "150x150>", 
#                                   :large     => "800x600>", 
#                                   :hd => "1920x1080>" 
#                               }
end
```

Couldn't find any clear information related to this error that seemed relevant to my configuration, so I'd appreciate some more experienced eyes looking over this with me. I'll post more info if needed.

Comment: Can you show the Image model please?

Comment: There's the image model as it is right now. I commented out the styles because I'm getting "identify" command not working messages now. I'm using Cygwin on Windows 7, which tends to be a source of trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is related to Paperclip and/or ImageMagick, perhaps involving my Windows/Cygwin configuration. Changing some environment variables seems to have allowed me to bypass this issue and move onto the `....jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command.` messages.

Any help on that would be appreciated but it looks like that's a topic that's already covered by existing questions, which I'm reading through now (no luck so far).

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue for some time now. I made the following changes in "form_for" -

```
<%= form_for :image, :as => @image, :url => { :action => "create" }, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
```

Now POST goes to /images and the missing route error message does not come anymore.

Comment: Interesting workaround. I'm not sure what changed but my problem seems to have disappeared on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Change the form_for parameters like this:

```
<%= form_for @image, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

<% end %>
```

I have just tested it, it should work.

Comment: No change. Same error still showing after submitting the form.

Comment: The issue seems to be related to Paperclip and/or ImageMagick not functioning as expected, as removing the `f.file_field :img` line (and nothing else) brought back normal expected functionality without the file field.

Comment: That is weird. Unless there is something wrong with your Image model, I don't know where the problem is, you are using paperclip as it should be! The problem is that the POST action is associated to images/new (which is wrong it should be associated to /images)...

Comment: Hmmm mysterious. Well the problem seems to be resolved for now. Not really sure what change did it.

Comment: OK. When you find out let me know, I'm curious :)

Comment: Haven't been able to pinpoint what change fixed it, but it was probably something as simple as restarting the app. Thanks for the input. I am using the form parameters as you recommended, which may have been a factor.